# Using TDS sync with Azure PaaS and Sitecore 9

Tags: azure, tds, deployment, paas

We're setting up a QA environment in Azure PaaS and we're working to figure out the best way to publish things. The code seems to be easy with VS 2017, but we're trying to figure out how to get TDS working. We tend to use the "sync with Sitecore" feature to do our syncing, so I'd prefer to find a way to use that if at all possible.

Does this involve using the NuGet packages that come with the TDS install, or is there another way to do it, or one that would be recommended and documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contacted TDS support, and they suggested a manual deployment. So I did the following:

1. Add the _DEV folder from your local instance to your VS project and publish it to the Azure App Service. (I used this method because you can't add folders through Cloud Explorer, only files.)
2. Using Cloud Explorer, upload the HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.dll file to the bin directory.
3. Test the sync with just the Sitecore Web URL filled in (leave the folder field blank).

After that, you should get a sync-up with the Test button and be able to go from there.